# ¿Cómo instalo Mariadb en mi hosting?

Tags: mariadb

Estoy realizando un sistema administrativo y quiero que el gestor de base de datos sea Mariadb pero mi hosting tiene el popular Mysql.

Ya tengo Mariadb instalado en el pc y ya he realizado pruebas de conexión y todo bien el mi localhost, pero no se como probar la conexión cuando este en el hosting.

Realicé un CRUD sencillo para probar la conexión con Mariadb en mi pc por medio del localhost y funciono muy bien, pero ahora quiero probar ese CRUD en mi hosting a ver como va, pero no se como subir la base de datos de Mariadb al hosting para probar la conexión. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Usa el servidor de MySQL tal y como usas el de MariaDB, pocas diferencias vas a encontrarte entre ambos :)

Comment: pero es que no se como subir la base de datos a mi hosting por que este maneja solo mysql

Comment: La inmensa mayoría de los hosting hacen uso del phpMyAdmin, importa desde éste tu .sql con todas las instrucciones que generan tu base de datos y lo tendrás. El acceso al phpMyAdmin lo encontrarás en el cpanel del hosting